# Python list slicing and indexing, better way

Tags: python

I have a given number 15. I have to group it with each group of 5 elements, and get tuple as follows.

```
num = 15
div = int(15/3)


groups = list(zip(range(div), range(div, div+div), range(div+div, div+div+div)))

for group in groups:
   print (group)


(0, 5, 10)
(1, 6, 11)
(2, 7, 12)
(3, 8, 13)
(4, 9, 14)
```

It is printing expected result. However, what would be better way of doing it?

Answer (score 3):

To specifically use slicing, you step by `div` in a slice of `list(range(num))`:

```py
num = 15
div = int(15/3)
num_list = list(range(num))

for idx in range(div):
    print(num_list[idx::div])
```

Edit: including `num_list` optimisation thanks to @Jordan Brière.

Comment: `list(range(num))` should ideally be assigned outside the loop; there is no reason to do so for each iterations.

Comment: @Oliver.R Or you could've sliced the range, that would avoid the space overhead.

Comment: @HeapOverflow I originally sliced the ranges, however I discovered that this returns another range generator - as the question seems to expect an iterable rather than an iterator, I figured explicit list conversion would give more evident results. Of course, slicing the list will be more efficient if the purpose of the resulting slice is to be iterated over.

Comment: @Oliver.R I meant you could've changed your `list(range(num))[idx::div]` to `list(range(num)[idx::div])`. Maybe you even would've realized then that you don't need to slice but can just use the other `range` parameters instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easy in one line, maybe I'm missing something

`lst = [(i, i+div, i+2*div) for i in range(div)]`

`[(0, 5, 10), (1, 6, 11), (2, 7, 12), (3, 8, 13), (4, 9, 14)]`